# IE9 and IE8 loading image set a width

Tags: jquery, html

```
var img_src="/xxx.jpg";
var img = new Image();
img.src = img_src;
 //img.height=height;
 img.width=200;
 img.removeAttribute('height');
```

The Image is loading with default size in IE8 and IE9 and i have checked it in google chrome and firefox it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Width` or `Height` have to be set with units like:

```
img.width = "200px";
```

Comment: `200px` should be in quotes, like this: `"200px"`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect IE overwrites the width and height attributes when the image loads. To work around the problem, use `img.style.width = "200px"; img.style.height = "auto";`.